# Interpretation of logistic regression: can I convert the coefficient change to probability change?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

In classic interpretation of logistic regression, We convert the coefficients to odds changes (using exponent). For example, if the coefficient is $1.0$, $\exp(1.0)=2.7$, we say the odds is $2.7$ times higher.

My question is that: can we talk in probability changes, using odd changes is still not convinenet? Say if the coefficient is $1.0$, the probability will increase or multiply or (other relationship) by $x$ amount?

I think the relationship is just `plogis` (as shown in plot), but how can I talk in English?

[image]

Comment: Because the rate of change of probability varies (tremendously) with the probability itself, you must first name a specific point on the curve.

Comment: @whuber so I should say like. Suppose we are at 0.5 probability, increase 1 unit of x will make odds 2.7 times larger, and make the probability change by $y$ amount?

Comment: @whuber is the reason we talk about odds change because it can "automatically" consider the none linear relationship "different point on the curve"?

Comment: In its ordinary form, with a logistic link function, logistic regression expresses probabilities in terms of a logistic function--that is, log odds.  When you use a different link the probabilities will be expressed in some different way.  Thus, the right way to interpret coefficients depends on the link function you use.